# profile2_load only working for current user

Tags: users

I have overridden page.tpl.php for a profile type and am trying to load a profile from the template. It is not working as expected. I can only load a profile for the currently logged in user but not for other users.

I want to load the profile for the user whose profile is currently being viewed. The pid is passed in from the url so that arg(1) is the pid. Here is what I'm trying

```
$pid = arg(1);
$profile = profile2_load($pid);
var_dump($profile);
```

The var_dump returns: bool(false)

I'm doing this logged-in as admin and admin has a pid=15

```
$profile = profile2_load(15);
var_dump($profile);
```

This returns a fully loaded profile.

As an experiment I tried profile2_load_by_user and the result is similar. For the user currently being viewed with pid=15 the uid=7

```
$profile = profile2_load_by_user(7);
var_dump($profile);
```

var_dump returns: array(0) { }

Doing the same for the currently logged in user (uid=1)

```
$profile = profile2_load_by_user(1);
var_dump($profile);
```

returns a fully loaded profile

I have checked permissions for profiles and "My Profile: View any profile" is set for 'Authenticated user'.

So it appears that I can load a profile for the currently logged in user but not for any other user. Anyone know how to resolve this?
Thank you!

Comment: have you seen this? It might solve your problem. https://drupal.org/node/1819920

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I did look at it. He/she has View any profile set for anonymous users which I can't do given my sites requirements. However I gave it a try and it made no difference. His/her other suggestion is to use profile2_load_by_user (which requires uid) instead of profile2_load (which requires pid). Since I don't have uid available I can't user profile2_load_by_user. In fact, one of the reasons I'm trying to load the profile is to get the uid of the user whose profile is being viewed.

Comment: So I had things a bit backwards. arg(1) was returning uid, not pid so I need to rethink this.